# Hibernate Annotation based Query executing Error?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, hql

Actually in my Hibernate Annotation based Application have theree ValueObject classes(Bean class) these are..

```
public Class CourseVO{
       @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;
    }
```

SKillsetVO class

```
public Class SkillsetVO{
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="COURSE_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private CourseVO courseSID;
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="SKILLSET_COURSE",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="SKILLSET_ID",referencedColumnName="S_ID")},inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="S_ID")})
  private Set<CourseVO> course;}
```

TimetableVO class

```
public class TimetableVO{
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="SKILLSET_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private SkillsetVO skillsetSID;
}
```

**Note** above code Primarikey called S_ID have contain another class called AbstractVO so my all classes are extends this AbstractVO class so no problem on Primary Key cration...
Now in my Business logic i wrote a query :

```
select tt from TimetableVO tt join tt.skillsetSID.course c where c.name in (:courseNames)
```

then i'm giving :courseName like 'java' then it is giving **`error`**  `SKILLSET_COURSE table not exist`
yes it is correct i'm only creating Three table according to ValueObjects...but hibernate can do this ..Please help me to write query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hbm2ddl` property to `create` or `update`. Or manually open the console and issue `CREATE` statement.

Comment: Thankyou for your replay... but in previously i'm executing same structure of query and value object annotaions also in that time not giving any error why? now only giving error? i think my query is problem or i miss annotaion in values object class...

Comment: Try this `@JoinTable(name="SKILLSET_COURSE",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="SKILLSET_ID")},inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="COURSE_ID")})`

Comment: Or change to `FetchType.LAZY` so you don't have to load orphans.