# Oracle sequence with Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have my application with Spring 3 that went so well. Basically the client wanted to migrate db from MySQL to Oracle. So everything is right; the problem is presented with the sequence of Oracle. I tried in every way to configure Hibernate but I always get the error

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assi

gned before calling save():     
org.hibernate.id.Assigned.generate(Assigned.java:52)
        org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117)
        org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
        org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
        org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
        org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
        org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:735)
        org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:727)
        org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:723)
        it.openingcode.vwh.dao.AbstractHibernateDAOImpl.save(AbstractHibernateDAOImpl.java:48)
        it.openingcode.vwh.dao.AbstractHibernateDAOImpl.save(AbstractHibernateDAOImpl.java:20)
        it.openingcode.vwh.services.AbstractCrudServiceImpl.save(AbstractCrudServiceImpl.java:70)
        it.openingcode.vwh.services.AbstractCrudServiceImpl.saveAll(AbstractCrudServiceImpl.java:77)
        it.openingcode.vwh.services.PrivilegiServiceImpl.updateFromGruppo(PrivilegiServiceImpl.java:92)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

In the model I added the annotation as follows:

> ```
>     @Id
>     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_entity_seq_gen")
>     @SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="SEQ_PROFILI")
>     @Column(name = "ID")
>     private Long id;
> ```

Comment: Did you check the related posts at the right?

Answer (score 1):

Put this annotation if you want to use it with Oracle

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="my_entity_seq_gen")
```

Comment: then delete the item

@SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="SEQ_PROFILI")

Comment: @FlavioMerolli You shouldn't delete it, the sequence generator is responsible to generate values. It uses database objects that simulate a sequence values. In oracle it's native object, in mysql it's a table. You should add nullable=false to the id field. Update a table using http://stackoverflow.com/a/13512585/573032